# Linking Math library to a C90 code using GCC

Tags: gcc, math.h, c89

I would like to compile a simple C90 code utilizing math library:

*main.c:*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf("M_PI: %f\n", M_PI);
}
```

I use GCC compiler and use option -ansi -pedantic to enforce C90 standard.

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -lm main.c
```

But it doesn't compile. The following is the error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:25: error: ‘M_PI’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:7:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

My question is, why? Does C90 standard prohibits the use of math library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M_PI isn't defined when strict iso standard is required. Look on [this](http://www.sbin.org/doc/glibc/libc_19.html) page under trigonometric functions. It is suggested that when using -ansi, just define it yourself:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327
```

Answer (score 2):

M_PI is generally declared as a macro and there is an explicit guard `#if !defined(_ANSI_SOURCE)` (at least in OSX), which suggests that the ANSI implementation doesnt support it

for gcc you can also use `-std=c90` to force C90